# Proper way of Redirecting in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I go back to home using Javascript?

I am here...

> localhost/Home/Alpha/Beta.aspx

if i use this `windows.location("Home.aspx");` it gets an error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even though the duplicate question has jQuery in the title, the answer has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: It says "The file '/Home/Alpha/Home.aspx' does not exist." It's really weird.

Comment: Well, does the file exist?

Comment: yes it exists.

i am using a localhost to test it..

so I am now at localhost/home/alpha/beta.aspx

when i click submit... it should go back to home.aspx.

how do i get about it? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is:

```
window.location = 'url'
```

Comment: This is resolved guys! I saw the duplicate article! Thanks to all of you!